# Failure sending mail in c#

Tags: c#, smtp

In this code the result is failure sending mail as message box shown,
     please guide me where   i did mistake.
            i tried it in many ways i didn't get. Thanks in advance

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {
   try

   {

     MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
     msg.To.Add("someone@gmail.com");
     MailAddress address = new MailAddress("someone@gmail.com ");
     msg.From = address;
     SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
     client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
     client.EnableSsl = true;
     client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
     client.Port = 25;
     NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("someone@gmail.com", "password");
     client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
     client.Credentials = credentials;


     client.Send(msg);


   } catch (Exception ex) {

     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }

 }
```

```
 <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
   <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="25" userName="someone@gmail.com" password="password" />
 </smtp>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on `failure`. Are you getting any exception? if so, could you embed it within our post. Is the email just not going through?

Comment: I've tried in another way but it shows the WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'Failure sending mail.'

Comment: MailAddress address = new MailAddress("someone@gmail.com"); // Remove space and try Port 587

Comment: try with port 587

Answer (score 0):

Change port="25" to port="587" 
And turn on less secure option in your gmail setting